# Query a marker that alraedy exists on the google map by it's lat and long and programmatically trigger a click event on it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to programmatically click on a marker, and I found this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({});
new google.maps.event.trigger( marker, 'click' );
```

It works well, but the code creates a new marker.

What I don't know how to do, is to "query" a marker that is already on the map by it's coordinates (lat and lng)
So, var marker would be something like this:

```
var marker = google.maps.query(lat, lng);
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: there is a marker collection, whereby you can iterate all the markers, examine the lat/lon, and click() any that fir the bill. look at the marker help section fro example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add all marker in array:

```
 var markersArray = [];

 markersArray.Push(marker);
```

Then on search:

```
 if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
               if(markersArray[i].position.lat() == 'yourlat' && markersArray[i].position.lng() == 'yourlng' )
                   new google.maps.event.trigger( markersArray[i], 'click' );
            }

        }
```

this not tested. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The idea by @Irfan works with a minor change.
Google happens to add precision to markers. For example a marker added at (60.1234, 20.5678) will return a lat/lng such as (60.1234xxxxxx, 20.5678xxxxx).
So comparing marker position returned from map to the lat/lng you used to set position of the markers wont work, possible solutions include rounding the values and then comparing or using some other parameters for comparison.